# ¿Como truncar decimales en columna de datagridview c#?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo un `DataGrid` que recibe su información desde la base de datos por medio de un SP, en uno de los campos, requiero truncar a dos decimales en lugar de redondear de forma que si tengo un valor como `99.9999578`, se quede en `99.99` y no se redondee a `100`.

Intenté con un formato personalizado `##0.00####` y `MaxInputLength` para tratar de limitar los caracteres que se muestran en la celda pero no funcionó.

Comment: Deja el código de cómo llenas el `DataGrid` así es más fácil ayudarte!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba a darle este formato a la columna

```
dataGridView1.Columns["TuColumna"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

Comment: Ese formato si me deja dos posiciones después del punto, pero igual redondea

Comment: Tienes razón.Tienes acceso al diseño del SP? Si tienes acceso puedes darle este formato al campo round([tucampo],2,1). La otra solución que se me ocurre (poco chapuza) es que recorras la tabla y ejecutes tabla["campo"] = Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDecimal(tabla["campo"])) * 100) / 100;